# How to Download a xml content to a file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to download a xml file,but i have a xml content in a string.

```
 public FileResult Download(string id)//guid
    {
        string fid = Convert.ToString(id);

        var model = service.GetAllDefinitions().First(x => x.ID == id);            
        var definitionDetails = new StatisticDefinitionModel(model);
        var definition = definitionDetails.ToXml;
         //in this definition i have xml content not a path
        string fileName = definitionDetails.Name + ".xml";
        string contentType = "text/xml";

        return File(definition , contentType);
    }
```

but this is not working,got error like illegal path.

Thanks,

Comment: You should be getting a warning because you are not using `fileName` in your function. Probably you can work from there.

Comment: So you have a XML structure in a string and want to box that in a file and return it? Why don't you return the XmlDocument directly?

Comment: @Gorpik -adding fileName also same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download xml file in asp.net using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860807/how-to-download-xml-file-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 
Only the first option will work. Also, specify a default file name for client:

```
 return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(definition), contentType, "somefilename.xml");
```

Comment: but my xml is using encoding="utf-16" ,this is not there in Encoding

Comment: What this mean? Your `definition` variable is a common .net string object. Also, return a UTF-16 for brownser is not a good idea. Is there any particular reason to use UTF-16?T

Comment: i dont no why my team is using UTF-16,is there any problem with using this?

Comment: Web browsers and many applications behave not very well with UTF-16.  http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

Comment: Also it's safe to send the file for client as UTF-8.