# How to download xml file in asp.net using C#

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am using an web application **asp.net with mvc3**. I am new to mvc3. I am having a download button on my webpage. when i am going to click the download button ,I want to able to **open that XML File**.

I have tried with some code changes in **ActionResult** but I didnt get the file opened. By using the below mentioned code I am getting a download popup. whenever i am going to open the file I am getting some exception as shown below. Can anyone please help me for do this? Help me to resolve this problem . :-)

Thanks in Advance.

My code in controller is:

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
{
    string fid = Convert.ToString(id);

    var model = service.GetAllDefinitions().First(x => x.ID == id);
    var definitionDetails = new StatisticDefinitionModel(model);
    var definition = definitionDetails.ToXml;

    string fileName = definitionDetails.Name + ".xml";
    string contentType = "text/xml";

    return File(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(definition), contentType, fileName);
   }
```

The exception is:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing   resource 'file:///C:/Users/asub/Downloads/fileNamegd...

<
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return FileResult it will be file, if you return string it will be open in browser.

**Update**:
This code will return file for downloading

```
public FileResult GetXmlFile()
{
    string xml=""; //string presented xml
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
    writer.WriteRaw(xml);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var fileStreamResult = File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "xml.xml");
    return fileStreamResult;        
}
```

Comment: Can you give me the sample result?

Comment: thanks for your nice code. I used your code nd I am getting some exception like " System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream " .Can you please have a look on this?

Comment: Oh. i did this again. Use it without "using" (i update answer)

Comment: I removed the using but still I am getting some other exception in browser like "XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/asub/Downloads/xml.xml'. "

Comment: Why you use contentType "text/xml"? And what are you doing with it on client? And could you show what is in variable definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a byte array, you need a Stream. Just pass a stream from your definition:

```
    public FileResult Download(string id) {
        string fid = Convert.ToString(id);

        var model = service.GetAllDefinitions().First(x => x.ID == id);
        var definitionDetails = new StatisticDefinitionModel(model);
        var definition = definitionDetails.ToXml;

        string fileName = definitionDetails.Name + ".xml";
        string contentType = "text/xml";

        return File(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(definition)), contentType, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this exception by using above code "A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/asub/AppData/Local/Micros... < "

Comment: Change the name to be a valid file name, you cannot use weird characters that you normally can't use in a Windows-based operating system. Use something like this; string fileName = new string((definitionDetails.Name + ".xml").Where(x => !Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(x)).ToArray());