# How to download a xml content in a xml file

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download xml file in asp.net using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860807/how-to-download-xml-file-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp)

can anyone please help how to download the xml (which is in string).I am using MVC3

Mycode;

```
 public FileResult Download(string id)
    {  
        var model = service.GetAllDefinitions().First(x => x.ID == id);
        var definitionDetails = new StatisticDefinitionModel(model);
        string xmlString = definitionDetails.ToXml;
     //string presented xml  

        string fileName = definitionDetails.Name + ".xml";

            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
            writer.WriteRaw(xmlString);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var fileStreamResult = File(stream, "application/xml", fileName);
            return fileStreamResult; 

    }
```

but this not working.gives an error

Error:

XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource

Thanks,

Comment: xml for create a table.xml is working fine,have uploaded in db table.

Comment: when i copied a content from xmlString,its working fine.but when i tried to download its getting an error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a xml stream here, just return the bytes.

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
{  
    var model = service.GetAllDefinitions().First(x => x.ID == id);
    var definitionDetails = new StatisticDefinitionModel(model);
    string xmlString = definitionDetails.ToXml;
    string fileName = definitionDetails.Name + ".xml";


    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString), "application/xml", fileName);
}
```

Comment: i also tried this way.got an error like The XML page cannot be displayed Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/asubramaniam/AppData/Local/Micros... <

Comment: OK, so you have a error on your xml definition. Paste the xml here. Probably the error is on root node.

Comment: i have checked the xml..there is no error,and also when i get the content from  xmlString its working fine.its happens for all my xml files which is my db's.is there any browser broblem?

Comment: I think the problem could be some namespace declaration on the root element. The message "Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet" says that some XSL used for your xml is not available or has an error. But maybe the default browser xsl for xml could cause de problem. Hard to say. Paste the xml root declaration here.

Comment: Ok. 1) you have to set an absolute uri for xmlns and xsi:schemaLocaton. In your case you have to prefix g.gpp... with "http://". 2) There is a ';' after xmlns attribute that should't be there. 3) After correct this issues the xml works fine on my browser. Try it and see what happens. If it not works you'll need to inspect the response as received by the browser (looking for encoding headers for example) or try change the encode to utf-8. For file and stream utf-8 is almost the standard, you only use another enconding if you have a good reason to do.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <Statistic Name="CompAPS" Type="table" xmlns="http://g.gpp.com/AnalyticPageModel/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://g.gpp.com/AnalyticPageModel/2.0 AnalyticPageModel.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: My xml is looks what you said.error here because it shows like a link..will try with changing of encoding